# How can I undo what I did when I accidentally set another person than me as the only reader of an e-mail in Lotus Notes 8.5?

Tags: lotus-notes

When we press the keys Alt+Enter over an e-mail in Lotus Notes, a little window with tabs on the top of it opens. One of the tabs is a key, and there you choose who is able to see the e-mail in matter. The thing is, I accidentally deselected myself and selected a colleague of mine. Now, he is the only one that can see this e-mail. He also have access to my inbox via his Lotus Notes. How can I undo this setting?
Thanks!!

Comment: You can not undo the change so ask him to add you back :-)

Comment: Get your administrator to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Two quick fixes.. Have your colleague add you back as a reader on the email... or tell your Admin you deleted it and need it restored back before you made said change.  Any admin worth his salt should have Transaction Logging on, and can restore using these logs up until the minute before you made the change, and they can just Copy and Paste from restored DB.

Comment: "Any admin worth his salt should have Transaction Logging on, and can restore using these logs up until the minute before you made the change, and they can just Copy and Paste from restored DB."  That's funny. Why would he need to lie about deleting it anyway, he could just tell them what actually happened and have them fix it.